# How do I configure my wpa_supplicant to match these?

Tags: wireless-networking, freebsd, wpa-supplicant

How do I configure my wpa_supplicant (on FreeBSD) to match the windows params in the picture?

[image]

So far I have tried this in /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf :

```
ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
ctrl_interface_group=wheel
ap_scan=2
update_config=1

network={
  priority=1
  ssid= SSID
  proto=RSN
  key_mgmt=WPA-EAP
  eap=TLS
  identity= IDENTITY
  password= PASSWORD
}
```

Using `wpa_cli` to control WPA supplicant configuration:

Editing wpa_supplicant.conf and then `reconfigure` from the `wpa_cli` prompt

Then:

```
> status
wpa_state=SCANNING <======== What does that mean?
ip_address=192.168.15.68
>
```

Also I realise that the network I am trying to join may be hidden.

After adding `ap_scan=2` in the `wpa_supplicant.conf` file, I am also getting this:

```
<2>Association request to the driver failed
wpa_state=ASSOCIATING
ip_address=192.168.15.68
Supplicant PAE state=DISCONNECTED
suppPortStatus=Unauthorized
EAP state=DISABLED
```

and then this indefinitely

```
<2>Association request to the driver failed
<2>Authentication with 00:00:00:00:00:00 timed out.
<2>Trying to associate with SSID <SSID>
<2>Association request to the driver failed
<2>Authentication with 00:00:00:00:00:00 timed out.
<2>Trying to associate with SSID <SSID>
<2>Association request to the driver failed
<2>Authentication with 00:00:00:00:00:00 timed out.
```

**UPDATE 20131202 - THE QUESTION HAS EVOLVED INTO A DIFFERENT SET OF PARAMS THAT DO MAKE MORE SENSE.**

[image]
[image]

It's using a three tiers environment

Root CA (offline)

Intermediate CA (offline)

2 Issuing CAs (online)

I have those in Base64 with a .CER extension

Now how does it fit in the wpa_supplicant.conf ?

```
ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
ctrl_interface_group=wheel
ap_scan=2
update_config=1

network={
  priority=1
  mode=0
  scan_ssid=1
  ssid="SSID"
  proto=RSN
  key_mgmt=WPA-EAP
  eap=PEAP
  group=CCMP TKIP
  pairwise=CCMP TKIP
  phase1="peaplabel=1" 
  phase2="auth=MSCHAPV2"
  identity="IDENTITY"
  password="PASSWORD"
  ca_cert= ????
}
```

Comment: This is new to me. Is there a log file that I can check? I have been also trying to use wpa_cli. I am trying to match the params in the MS Windows config to http://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/network-wireless.html

Comment: I'm asking so we don't reinvent the wheel. I am assuming you spent some time reading up on how to set up wireless on FreeBSD and could not manage it. Please show us the exact commands you ran and explain how they failed.

Comment: Yes I have spent quite a few hours indeed. My question should have been ... how do I troubleshoot this issue? After a while I found out about wpa_cli. That should be of help. Terdon, honestly, I just don't know how to tackle this and where I can read for error messages... and how I can correct my params accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, that's a step in the right direction but what file is that? You haven't even told us what the issue is, can you not see the wifi card? Not connect at all? Connect to LAN but no internet? What is the output of `iwconfig`? What is your WiFi card? Have a look through [this](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/network-wireless.html) and [this](http://www.wonkity.com/~wblock/docs/html/wireless.html) (first 2 hits for "freeBSD wireless howto"), try their suggestions and update your Q with any results/problems.

Comment: Terdon, You could have just recommended to fire a few commands instead of pointing at docs on the web. I have spent hours on those before you even mentioning it. I can use Google. And iwconfig is not a command I have in my environment. I wonder if you are really willing to help after all.

Comment: You're quite right, I have not been very polite here, my apologies. I just take issue with the (many) posters here who expect us to google for them. With your latest update, it is clear that you are not one of them and my annoyance was not only rude but misplaced (which is why I had upvoted you yesterday, after the 1st edit). However, do note that _now_ we can see that i) your system recognizes your card, ii) you've edited `wpa_supplicant.conf`, iii) you've _tried_. None of this was evident in the 1st version of your post. Please add the exact commands and options you use also though.

Comment: No worries. My initial question lacked of content indeed. I just didn't know where to start. When I discovered wpa_cli command, I was able to try more in a more consistent manner. I have tried all sorts of settings. The only info I have is that screenshot, and I am trying to map those params to the FreeBSD world. Just now I wonder if I need to add the BSSID to the config... but I don't have it.

Comment: You should also be aware that (while this Q is on-topic and welcome to stay here) there are not many BSD people on SU. I recommend that **if** you don't get an answer after a few days here, you ask for the Q to be migrated to [unix.se] where there are more Unix gurus. By the way, are you running this as root or a normal user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a good starting place to fix this problem is the [FreeBSD Manpage for wpa_supplicant.conf](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=wpa_supplicant.conf&sektion=5), which presents several examples, one of which is:

```
# work network; use EAP-TLS with WPA; allow only CCMP and TKIP ciphers
network={
ssid="work"
scan_ssid=1
key_mgmt=WPA-EAP
pairwise=CCMP TKIP
group=CCMP TKIP
eap=TLS
identity="user@example.com"
ca_cert="/etc/cert/ca.pem"
client_cert="/etc/cert/user.pem"
private_key="/etc/cert/user.prv"
private_key_passwd="password"
}
```

This differs from your version of it in two key ways: there is a reference to AES encryption which was missing in your file (it is the CCMP mode, which is based on AES), and requires the existence of certificates. This last part is what leaves me befuddled in your Windows mask: in it there is no reference whatsoever to an authentication mechanism. There is no room for passwords (fair enough, it would not be WPA-EAP otherwise), but there is also no mention of certificates, which is what TLS needs.

In fact, from [Wikipedia's page on TLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#TLS_1.0),

> Transport Layer Security (TLS) .... use[s] X.509 certificates... As a consequence of choosing X.509 certificates, certificate authorities and a public key infrastructure are necessary to verify the relation between a certificate and its owner, as well as to generate, sign, and administer the validity of certificates...

In other words, since your Windows mask is adamant that `TLS` is being used, somewhere there must be the certificates referred to in the `wpa_supplicant.conf` file I quoted above. I cannot go beyond this point.

Edit:

to address joelmaranhao's latest question, I quote again from [FreeBSD Manpage for wpa_supplicant.conf](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=wpa_supplicant.conf&sektion=5):

> CERTIFICATES
>        Some EAP authentication methods require use of certificates.  EAP-TLS
>        uses both server- and client-side certificates, whereas EAP-PEAP and EAP-
>        TTLS only require a server-side certificate.

Edit n. 2:

The .CER certificate must be transformed into the format .PEM. You can do that even on-line [here](https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-converter.html). The last line in your new wpa_supplicant.conf is exactly the location of this certificate. Identity is your name at the server, the password is your password again on the wifi server. Are you sure the peal-label is 0? I cannot find it anywhere, if it does not work, try peap-label=1.

Comment: yes this is great help as it actually validates what I have been doing so far. I investigated for the certificates too, I was told, there isn't any. I didn't know about the Linux & Unix Stack exchange. Thanks

Comment: Marius, Would EAP-PEAP also require certificates installed on the client machine? (I have read the docs, but I am getting confused now, I have just read a doc saying that you only need a certificate on the server side, nothing else ...??)

Comment: @joelmaranhao I have added an edit to my original answer

Comment: @joelmaranhao Please check this Web page https://supportforums.cisco.com/docs/DOC-17544 to see whether you can extract more info about your wifi connection from your Windows system, things like certificates and/or passwords. Or maybe this one http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/import-or-export-certificates-and-private-keys or even this one http://www.utexas.edu/its/help/user-certs/813

Comment: I also managed to get more info on my side, I have new  WIndows config screenshot. It shows something a little different. It also use three tier environment for the CA ... so I have now quite a few certificates .CER but don't know what to do with it yet. Still studying the docs. Thanks for the extra info. I will read it now.

Comment: Yes Marius, I did manage to extract more info. See edits in the Question... it's a three tier CA environment, and I was provided with Base64 CER files ... 5 of them. See new screenshots

Comment: @joelmaranhao I have update my answer.

Comment: Regarding the certificates, I have 4 files: Root (offline), Intermediate (offline) and 2 Issuing certificates (online). The wpa_supplicant.conf only allows to ca_certs = ... Am I supposed to bundle these chain certificates into one file? and how is done?